# Binding a listView to display data associated with it in another listView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

dear StackOverflow users. There's a task I'm given: I have a list of students that I get from JSON.

```
[
    {
        "Name":         "Grant",
        "Groupname":    "Group1"
    },
    {
        "Name":         "Tim",
        "Groupname":    "Group2"
    },
    {
        "Name":         "Spencer",
        "Groupname":    "Group3"
    }
    .....
]
```

Then I have two listBoxes: first for Groups, second for Students belonging to that group.
The problem I cannot get to solve: displaying students of the currently selected group in listBox using Binding and DataContext. So I need help. Declarations of Student and Group:

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Groupname { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; } // how many students are in this group

    public List<Student> Students = new List<Student>();

    public Group()
    {
    }

    public Group(string name, int count)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Count = count;
    }
}
```

The code below uses List of groups and each group has a list of students. And at this moment I'm stuck.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    List<Group> groups = new List<Group>();
    
    // I excluded json deserialization and Lists initialization code...

    InitializeComponent();

    foreach (var x in groups)
    {
        GroupsView.Items.Add(x.Name);

        foreach (var y in x.Students)
        {
            StudentsView.Items.Add(y);
        }
    }
}
```

The listBoxes in XAML

```
<ListBox Name="GroupsView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="172" Margin="48,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="206"/>

<ListBox Name="StudentsView"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="172" Margin="306,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="364">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="{Binding Path=Id}"></Run>
                <Run Text="{Binding Path=Name}"></Run>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I know it has something to do with XAML but I suddenly got this problem and need to finish it quickly. And last time I used C# in 2017 so please excuse my silly question. If anyone could help, I'd be so grateful

Comment: Hello  and welcome. In the MainWindow(), foreach, you are adding all students from all the groups in the student list view. you might wanna close that part. Maybe just add the first group's students. You need to implement .SelectedValueChanged  method for GroupsView listbox.  In the method, clear the current student list and fill the StudentsView with the students from the selected group.

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your reply! I apologize I cannot upvote your suggestion

Comment: No problem. I didn't write a fully coded answer so it's ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First, you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for MainWindow, so you will have OnPropertyChanged();

```
public class MainWindow : INotifyPropertyChanged
```

See here, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

And in the constructor, add: `this.DataContext = this;`

2. Then add following properties:

```
private List<Group> _groups;

public List<Group> Groups
{
    get { return _groups; }
    set { _groups = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
}

private Group _selectedGroup;


public Group SelectedGroup
{
    get { return _selectedGroup; }
    set 
    { 
        _selectedGroup = value; 
        OnPropertyChanged();
        if (_selectedGroup != null)
        {
            Students = _selectedGroup.Students;
        }
    }
}

private List<Student> _students;

public List<Student> Students
{
    get { return _students; }
    set { _students = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
}
```

3. Data binding:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource=”{Binding Groups}” SelectedItem=”{Binding SelectedGroup}” … />
<ListBox ItemsSource=”{Binding Students}” … />
```

Comment: Frank, thanks so much! I'm gonna give it a shot! I was so lost, now I get the direction